# Immediately reverse CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add the `.shown` class to my `#overlay` I would like the opacity to fade in for 2secs, then immediately reverse and fade out for 2 seconds, creating a sort of "flashing" effect.

I tried just removing the class but that doesn't show any animation at all. This is my sample markup/CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    This is some text
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay {
    ...
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay.shown {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

**Attemped JS:**

```
// Wait 2 seconds from page load...
setTimeout(function() {
    // Add shown class to trigger animation
    document.getElementById("overlay").classList.add("shown");
    // Want to remove the class and hoped this would reverse the animation...
    // it doesn't
    document.getElementById("overlay").classList.remove("shown");
}, 2000);
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/aJVj4/)

Comment: Can you use jquery for same?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Try including the transition property in the #overlay.shown selector as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use css animation with keyframes

```
@keyframes myFlash
{
0%   {opacity:0;}
50%  {opacity:0.3;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myFlash /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity:0;}
50%  {opacity:0.3;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}

#overlay {
    ...
    opacity: 0;
}
#overlay.shown {
animation:myFlash 2s;
-webkit-animation:myFlash 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: you dont need to remove class with this solution just add it and when you need to flash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a second timeout after the first animation completes..

```
// Wait 2 seconds from page load...
setTimeout(function() {
    // Animate Forward
    document.getElementById("overlay").classList.add("shown");
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Animate Back
        document.getElementById("overlay").classList.remove("shown");
    },2000);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of changes i have done to achieve your out put please check following code

```
Your css
#outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#overlay {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #336699;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay.shown {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Your js

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#overlay").addClass("shown");
   var def = $('#overlay').promise();
    def.done(
       function () {
          $('body').stop().delay(5000).queue(function(){
        $("#overlay").removeClass("shown");
    });

    });


}, 2000);
```

There was no delay between first and second so how it will show animation which you have done

Please check working demo.....[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wiyiyuxa/1/)

Comment: Javascript can be used?

Comment: Technically yes, but Taimour's solution is what I'm looking for - a pure CSS solution

Comment: Because you have provided a jQuery answer to a question not tagged as such. Therefore, as the downvote button says, it is not helpful to me.  It is also not the right way to go about this. Adding 90k of library for something which can be achieved in less than 10 lines of CSS